# How can I permanently delete my Myspace account?

Tags: account-management, myspace

Every man and his dog seems to be moving off to Facebook, so what is the point keeping my Myspace account open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a quick process.

1. Log in to your myspace.com account
2. Click My Account next to sign out
3. Click on the Account tab
4. Click Cancel Account
5. Give them a reason and confirm

Comment: it did not work what do i do now

Answer (score 0):

These steps worked for me as recently as April 2011

1. After logging into MySpace click on the My Stuff tab
2. Click on Account Settings in the left hand column
3. Scroll down to Account Settings & Privacy
4. Click Cancel Account
5. Click Cancel Account button again
6. Click Reason, and then the Cancel Account button again
7. Click Cancel Account button a few more times (they asked me like three times)
8. A message should pop up saying they will send you an email to confirm cancellation
9. Follow instructions sent in the email